# XSLT Select all nodes containing a specific substring

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to write an XPath that will select certain nodes that contain a specific word.
In this case the word is, "Lockwood".  The correct answer is 3. Both of these paths give me 3.

```
count(//*[contains(./*,'Lockwood')])
count(BusinessLetter/*[contains(../*,'Lockwood')])
```

But when I try to output the text of each specific node

```
//*[contains(./*,'Lockwood')][1]
//*[contains(./*,'Lockwood')][2]
//*[contains(./*,'Lockwood')][3]
```

Node 1 ends up containing all the text and nodes 2 and 3 are blank.

Can some one please tell me what's happening or what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XPathFunctions.xsl"?>
<BusinessLetter>
 <Head>
  <SendDate>November 29, 2005</SendDate>
  <Recipient>
   <Name Title="Mr.">
    <FirstName>Joshua</FirstName>
    <LastName>Lockwood</LastName>
   </Name>
   <Company>Lockwood &amp; Lockwood</Company>
   <Address>
    <Street>291 Broadway Ave.</Street>
    <City>New York</City>
    <State>NY</State>
    <Zip>10007</Zip>
    <Country>United States</Country>
   </Address>
  </Recipient>
 </Head>
 <Body>
  <List>
   <Heading>Along with this letter, I have enclosed the following items:</Heading>
   <ListItem>two original, execution copies of the Webucator Master Services Agreement</ListItem>
   <ListItem>two original, execution copies of the Webucator Premier Support for Developers Services Description between Lockwood &amp; Lockwood and Webucator, Inc.</ListItem>
  </List>
  <Para>Please sign and return all four original, execution copies to me at your earliest convenience.  Upon receipt of the executed copies, we will immediately return a fully executed, original copy of both agreements to you.</Para>
  <Para>Please send all four original, execution copies to my attention as follows:

 <Person>
    <Name>
     <FirstName>Bill</FirstName>
     <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    </Name>
    <Address>
     <Company>Webucator, Inc.</Company>
     <Street>4933 Jamesville Rd.</Street>
     <City>Jamesville</City>
     <State>NY</State>
     <Zip>13078</Zip>
     <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
   </Person>
  </Para>
  <Para>If you have any questions, feel free to call me at <Phone>800-555-1000 x123</Phone> or e-mail me at <Email>bsmith@webucator.com</Email>.</Para>
 </Body>
 <Foot>
  <Closing>
   <Name>
    <FirstName>Bill</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
   </Name>
   <JobTitle>VP of Operations</JobTitle>
  </Closing>
 </Foot>
</BusinessLetter>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation, complete and easy solution and for a useful rule to remember. :)

Answer (score 11):

> But when I try to output the text of
>   each specific node
>
> ```
> //*[contains(./*,'Lockwood')][1] 
> //*[contains(./*,'Lockwood')][2] 
> //*[contains(./*,'Lockwood')][3]
> ```
>
> Node 1 ends up containing all the text
>   and nodes 2 and 3 are blank

**This is a FAQ.**

```
//SomeExpression[1]
```

is not the equivalent to

```
(//someExpression)[1]
```

The former selects all `//SomeExpression` nodes that are the first child of their parent.

The latter selects the first (in document order) of all `//SomeExpression` nodes in the whole document.

**How does this apply to your problem?**

```
//*[contains(./*,'Lockwood')][1]
```

This selects all elements that have at least one child whose string value contains 'Lockwood' and that are the first such child of their parent. All three elements that have a text node containing the string 'Lockwood' are the first such child of their parents, so the result is that three elements are selected.

```
//*[contains(./*,'Lockwood')][2]
```

There is no element that has a child with string value containing the string 'Lockwood' and is the second such child of its parent. No nodes are selected.

```
//*[contains(./*,'Lockwood')][3]
```

There is no element that has a child with string value containing the string 'Lockwood' and is the third such child of its parent. No nodes are selected.

**Solution**:

Use:

```
(//*[contains(./*,'Lockwood')])[1]
(//*[contains(./*,'Lockwood')])[2]
(//*[contains(./*,'Lockwood')])[3]
```

Each of these selects exactly the Nth element (N = {1,2,3}) selected by `//*[contains(./*,'Lockwood')]`, correspondingly: `BusinesLetter`, `Recipient` and `Body`.

**Remember**:

The `[]` operator has higher priority (precedence) than the `//` abbreviation.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Formaly from http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#NT-Predicate : *A predicate filters a node-set with respect to an axis to produce a new node-set* . And this `//*[1]` gets expanded to `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::*[1]`