# What xPath should I use to display the requested data?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I am using the following script to get the POST TITLE and the CONTENT of an RSS feed. The structure of it is: ( I guess i did not make any error)

```
<div id="feedBody">
<div id="feedContent">
<div class="entry">
<h3>TITLE OF POST</h3>
<div base="http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogspot/hyMBI" 
     class="feedEntryContent"
    > CONTENT OF POST </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>




<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogspot/hyMBI');
libxml_clear_errors();

$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xPath->query('????????????????');
foreach($links as $link) {
    printf("%s \n", $link->nodeValue);
}
?>
```

What xPath should I use to get the data? Is there any way of having them seperate?
Thanks a million, hopefully this is my last question on my project...

Comment: $dom->load(), not $dom->loadHTMLFile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should load the XML using `load`, not `loadHTMLFile`.

Judging by your variable name "$links", I guess you're wanting the values of the `<link>` elements inside the `<item>` elements. So construct an xpath query that says just that: `//item/link`.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. The above code is an example I found through a tutorial. I have done what you said, but how can I get the title and content instead of the link?

Comment: The easiest way to do that would be to fetch all `<item>` nodes with `//item`, then for each found node use `$xPath->query('/title`, $item)` to get the title and `$xPath->query('/description`, $item)` to get the content.

Comment: Exactly the clue I wanted ! As i see in the source of the RSS, I was wrong for the paths I entered. Your item/link item/title item/description made the trick! Now I am trying to seperate the image and the content. I read somewhere about strpos, but if you can have a look at it, that would be great. Thanks again!

Comment: Your best bet there might be to use `DOMDocument::loadHTML` to load up the HTML content of the description and use xpath to extract that too.

Answer (score 0):

Basic XPath: `//div[@class="entry"]` gets you an array of all entries. You can get the first (or only) entry with `//div[@class="entry"][1]`. With that, you can use `h3` to get the text of the title node, and `div[1]` to get the contents (if it's guaranteed that there's only one, otherwise specify the class).

You can put them together like `//div[@class="entry"][1]/h3` if you like, so that you only have to query the root node. Otherwise, save the new node for the next query, like:

```
$entries = $xPath->query('//div[@class="entry"][1]');
foreach($entry in $entries) {
  $title = $xPath->evaluate('h3[1]',$entry);
  $post = $xPath->evaluate('div[1]',$entry);
}
```

If your RSS returns a whole group of posts, you can leave off the first [1] and loop through the whole group this way.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply.. But it can't display me anything even with //div[@class="entry"]

Comment: Is the HTML above an actual snippet of the feed you're accessing? If not, post part of the actual feed.

Comment: `//div[@class="entry"][1]`" does not do what you say it does. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672997/xslt-select-all-nodes-containing-a-specific-substring/4674372#4674372